# Precision of double in this code is only 6 digits

Tags: c++

```
  double a_0_d = 2 * sqrt(3);
  double b_0_d = 3;
  double ak_d = 0, bk_d = 0;
  while ((a_0_d-b_0_d) != 0) {
      ak_d = a_0_d;
      bk_d = b_0_d;
      a_0_d = (2 * ak_d * bk_d) / (ak_d + bk_d);
      b_0_d = sqrt(a_0_d * bk_d);
      //cout << a_0_d << "     " << b_0_d << endl;
  }
  pi_double = a_0_d;
  cout << "The pi_double value at double precision is  = " << pi_double << endl;
```

Output: 3.14159

I thought the precision of double is 15 digits, is it possible that the output is converted to float data type?

Comment: **Displayed** precision of `double` is only 6 digits. That's the default.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
#include <iomanip>

cout << "The pi_double value at double precision is  = " << std::setprecision(15) << pi_double << endl;
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/0e1kE0)